# How to initialize a variable before it's value is decided?

Tags: javascript

I have a basic for loop where I determine the value, `'left'` or `'right'`,  of a variable called `animationDirection`.

How can I initialize this variable before the loop so that it can be defined with in it?

I've tried initializing it to `undefined`, by using `var animationDirection = undefined;` but this is frowned upon by javascript linter.

I've settled on the code below that defines animationDirection in the loop logic, but this seems like a bad idea because I'm initializing the variable with `var` twice.

Any ideas on how to better define the variable?

```
for (var i = 0; i < $selected.length; i++) {

    if (i < ($selected.length / 2)) {
        var animationDirection = 'left';
    } else {
        animationDirection = 'right';
    }

    $($selected[i])
        .css(animationDirection, animationOffset)
        .velocity(animation, animationConfig);
}
```

Comment: `var animationDirection; for(...`

Comment: @epascarello is that the same as `var animationDirection = undefined;`?

Comment: Beware of [variable declaration hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), as you seem to not know of it.

Comment: @acdcjunior I am aware of it how does that apply here?

Comment: @agconti They're not exactly the same, but accomplish a similar result. `var variable = undefined` explicitly *defines* a variable with the `undefined` value. But, either way, getting its value will produce `undefined`.

Comment: `$($selected[i])` could be rewritten as `$selected.eq(i)` assuming `$selected` is a jquery object as it seems to be.  Functionally the same, just cleaner (in my opinion).  Unrelated to the question or course.

Comment: @agconti It applies in the sense that you'd know that stating a `var` in wherever is the same as stating it in the top. The linter complains about `var myVar = undefined;` because it is redundant/pointless, not because it is bad.

Comment: @acdcjunior you're off base here. the question isnt about why the linter complains, but how to better define the variable in this case.

Comment: @agconti The question is about where to define the variable, and, knowing of hoisting, it is a no-brainer that the best location is at the **top**. But the linter complained about the variable being declared there. Knowing that the linter complained about the redundant assignment, not the location, this question becomes plain pointless. But, of course, you had to know those two things. Which, from your tone, you obviously did. So, yeah, I'm probably off base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var animationDirection,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < $selected.length; i += 1) {

    if (i < ($selected.length / 2)) {
        animationDirection = 'left';
    } else {
        animationDirection = 'right';
    }

    $($selected[i])
        .css(animationDirection, animationOffset)
        .velocity(animation, animationConfig);
}
```

Douglas Crockford's JSLint requires that variables be declared at the top of a function (not sure what lint you're using).

Here's a more concise approach that avoids the `for`-loop semantics (assuming here that `$selected` is a jQuery object) and makes the question of where to declare your variable much simpler:

```
$selected.each(function(i, e) {
    var animationDirection = (i < ($selected.length / 2)) ? "left" : "right";
    $(e).css(animationDirection, animationOffset)
        .velocity(animation, animationConfig);
});
```

Comment: what is the benefit of defining `i` out site the for loop statement?

Comment: @agconti Doublas Crockford's JSLint requires all variables be declared at the beginning of a function. The stated benefit is that this clearly demonstrates that the variable's scope extends throughout the whole function and not just the portion after where it is declared. See: http://jslinterrors.com/move-var-declarations-to-the-top-of-the-function/

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
for (var i = 0; i < $selected.length; i++) {
    $($selected[i])
        .css(i < ($selected.length / 2) ? 'left': 'right' , animationOffset)
        .velocity(animation, animationConfig);
}
```

Comment: This makes a good point, but it does not answer the OP's question, which pertains to how to define a javascript var outside a for loop.

Comment: this is a good answer, its much cleaner than my example and offers me a better solution to my question, +1.

Comment: why da heck would you down vote, how this would not work for this case? you down voting people piss me off here sometimes big time... so pedantic... ridiculous

Comment: Go ahead down vote as much as you want. still helped @agconti though with something at least...

Comment: thanks, mark it as an answer if you can, not sure if you can mark  down voted answers...

Comment: vote war!!! I voted this up, but don't think this should be marked as the answer this the principal question was about declaring variables without values.

Comment: @haimlit I agree, but only because of the question's title. i cant think of a better one to change to because it really is the heart of the question. MyP3uK should get his deserved upvotes and reputation. the down voters should adjust their votes.